# nearest street view image

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api, google-street-view

How to get the nearest GoogleStreetView image and its exact position with an inaccurate position? thanks to an other api?
Google maps do it, example :https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=45.755622,4.869343&hl=fr&num=1&t=m&z=16
but the API is less tolerant :
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=45.755622,4.869343&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&sensor=false

According to API documentation, we should use this kind of url : 
.../maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&location=40.720032,%20-73.988354&sensor=false&key=API_console_key

no possibility to check if a photo is available (parssing the photo color?)

(reversing: http://cbk0.googleapis.com/cbk?output=xml&ll=40.720032,%20-73.988354&cb_client=apiv3 give the exact position of an image, I used it on my android project but this webservice seems not maintained for a public use ?? :/)

Answer (score 2):

You may use [StreetViewService.getPanoramaByLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewService)

There is a radius-parameter, when he is less then 50 you will receive data for the nearest panorama(within 50 meters).

When no panorama is available within 50 meters you may increase the radius until you get a result.